# Get coordinates with xdotool upon user click and use them in an automation script

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, read, xdotool

I am trying to prompt the user "Click the confirm button" and use the coordinates as a variable in a script.

If the user clicks at 1285 786, I would like to click this coordinate once and then move the cursor down 10 pixels while clicking every pixel along the way.

So how would I use read -p "Click the confirm button" and then use the coordinates the user clicks as a variable?